# Unable to attach EC2 instance to a classic load balancer in AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have created an EC2 instance and a Classic Load Balancer in AWS CDK using typescript. But I'm unable to add that EC2 instance directly to that Load balancer.

```
this.Instance= new ec2.Instance(this, 'my-Instance', {
  vpc,
  instanceType: new InstanceType(instanceType),
  ...});
```

and load Balancer

```
this.Elb = new LoadBalancer(this, 'my-ELB', {
..
crossZone: true,
internetFacing: false,
...});
```

I'm looking to add this ec2 instance to this load balancer using something like this:

```
this.Elb.addEc2Instance(this.Instance)
```

but there isn't any such property available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finally worked for me. Putting it here so that no one else wastes as much time as I did in figuring this out.

`elbObj.instances` expects a string array of instance IDs. ([read here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html#cfn-ec2-elb-instances))

```
 const elbObj = this.elb.node.defaultChild as CfnLoadBalancer;
    if (elbObj) {
      elbObj.instances = [(this.jenkinsInstance.instanceId).toString()];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `LoadBalancer`. You have to place your instance in **autoscaling group** first. And then you attach the ASG to your LB as shown in the [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-elasticloadbalancing-readme.html):

```
const lb = new elb.LoadBalancer(this, 'LB', {
    vpc,
    internetFacing: true,
    healthCheck: {
        port: 80
    },
});

lb.addTarget(myAutoScalingGroup);
lb.addListener({
    externalPort: 80,
});
```